# Conditional Looping to get group based length of string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple R*C.I want to create a conditional loop 
which will check for the lengthiest string in a column and mark it as group1
and then compare its content with other strings in the column for match. The condition is that if there is any string present in the column which matches with the lengthiest string, it will be marked as group 1. If there is any new element present, then it will be marked as the next group.

```
   STR 
"G,D,E","F"  
"D,E,F","G"
"D,E","F"
"A,B","C"
"C","D"
"A","B"
```

Output Should be like:

```
   STR            Group  
 "G,D,E","F"        1   
 "D,E,F","G"        1
 "D,F","E"          1
 "D,E","F"          1
 "A,B","C"          2
 "C","D"            3 
 "A","B"            2
```

Comment: Is it a list of strings per row?

Comment: Actual data set included something different. For example, {G:D:E=>F}. I had split the string and removed the separators and curly brackets converting it in format: "G,D,E","F" .......

Answer (score 0):

This is a first go. I assume the given data structure is a data frame with two columns as it seems to be in your example.  Here is what I did:

```
str_1 <- c("G,D,E", "D,E,F", "D,E", "A,B", "C", "A")
str_2 <- c("F", "G", "F", "C", "D", "B")
str_df <- data.frame(str_1, str_2)
merged_str <- paste(str_df[,1], str_df[,2], sep=",")
str_list <- strsplit(merged_str, ",")

is_in_group <- function(letters, group){
  for (letter in letters) {
    if(!(letter %in% group)) {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

groups <- list() 
groups[[1]] <- str_list[[1]]
group_vec <- rep(0, length(str_list))
group_vec[1] <- 1

for (i in 2:length(str_list)) {
  curr_letters <- str_list[[i]]
  new_group = TRUE
  for (g in 1:length(groups)) {
    if(is_in_group(curr_letters, groups[[g]])) {
      group_vec[i] <- g
      new_group = FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  if (new_group) {
    groups[[length(groups)+1]] <- curr_letters
    group_vec[i] <- length(groups)
  }
}
```

Comment: Considering the provided data , it is ok. But what in case I have a huge number of data which is actually a "COLUMN" in a data frame having alpha-numeric data combinations.......something like "G7,D4,E5","F6" , "D4,E5,F6","G7"....and so on

Comment: You should give a dummy example such that we can get a clear view on the data structure of this dataframe. Can't you make some code that creates a small version of exactly what you mean? Because it's not fully clear when you say it in words to me :)

Comment: I do agree to the point u just said.....but the actual dataset is too complex to code. Original dataset was with factor (each row of data element as 1 factor).To be precise,"G,D,E","F" represents {Z:Q08A-00,Y:DB55,X:DB55} => {Z:A03F-00}...I hope i was able to help u understand.....

Comment: Can I assume you always have two columns in a dataframe with two strings contained of 1 or more letters ? It seems you're implying this..

Comment: Something like this: ```str_1 <- c("G,D,E", "D,E,F", "D,E", "A,B", "C", "A")
str_2 <- c("F", "G", "F", "C", "D", "B")
str_df <- data.frame(str_1, str_2)```. Where str_2 is the part behind => and str_1 is the one before and str_df combines them. Is this how your data is structured?

Comment: I am considering it as single string....that is how it will match....I have taken out "=>" this part from all the strings.....I will give u backdrop of this......the part before => refers to the cause and after refers to effect. So when we compare, we can check that G,D,E caused F.Similarly D,E,F caused G.So both can be clubbed under one group. When D,F caused E..and will be marked as part of group 1. If there is any new combination....then that will be marked as next group....

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the following are all the same group: ("D,E,F","G" ), ("D,E", "F,G"), ("D", "E,F,G"), ("D,F", "E,G"), ("D,G", "F,G"), ("G", "E,D,F") ....... Meaning, the apostrophes don't matter, you just want all combinations of the letters in the same group, right???? :p

Comment: Correct....all combination in same group.....("D,E,F","G") , ("D,E,F","G") , ("D,E","F"),
("E","F")....all will be one group.....if there is any new element...then it would b considered as another group.....

Comment: If you can imagine a parent-child relationship.....I am trying to figure out the parent nodes, in these case combinations....